# MongoDB Java update values

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have saved the following json in the mongoDB:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "1753242",
        "TYPE": "8003"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "4823034",
        "TYPE": "7005"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "4823034",
        "TYPE": "8003"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to change all `"Type" : "8003"` to `"Type" : "8"` with Java.
I do it like this:

```
   BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
   updateQuery.append("$set",
            new BasicDBObject().append("features.$.properties.TYPE", "8"));

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    searchQuery.append("features.properties.TYPE", "8003");

    collection.updateMulti(searchQuery, updateQuery);
```

The problem is, that `"features.$.properties.TYPE"` only selects and updates the value of the first element, but not of the other(s).
Does anybody know how to change ALL `"Type" : "8003"` to `"Type" : "8"` and not just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to get a subset of the array with just the elements you need to update, iterate the subset and for each element update the collection using the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

To get the subset, you would need to use the aggregation framework where the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator can be useful to generate this subset. For example, the following mongo shell operation shows how you can use the algorithm
described above to update your collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "features.properties.TYPE": "8003" } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "features": {
                "$filter": [                   
                   "input": "$features",
                   "as": "feature",
                   "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$feature.properties.TYPE", "8003" ] }
            }           
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        db.collection.updateOne(
            { "_id": doc._id, "features.properties.TYPE": "8003"  },
            { "$set": { "features.$.properties.TYPE": "8" }
        });
    });
});
```

Now a few points to note. Firstly, if your MongoDB version does not support the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator introduced in version `3.2. X` and newer, then consider using the [**`$setDifference`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator combo as fallback to filter the array elements in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline.

The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. [**`$setDifference`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) will then return a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final `features` array that has elements not related to the parent documents via the subdocument `TYPE` property:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "features.properties.TYPE": "8003" } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "features": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$features",
                            "as": "feature",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$feature.properties.TYPE", "8003" ] },
                                    "$$feature",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        db.collection.updateOne(
            { "_id": doc._id, "features.properties.TYPE": "8003"  },
            { "$set": { "features.$.properties.TYPE": "8" }
        });
    });
});
```

Secondly, doing the updates in a nested loop with O(N^2) complexity may suffer from performance penalties. In that regard, you can optimise your code by taking advantage of the [Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) which allows you to send the
updates as streamlined batches i.e. instead of sending each update request in to the server with each iteration, you can bulk up the update operations into a single request which is faster and more efficient. The following shows how you can leverage the updates using **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods)** method.

For **MongoDB version 3.0** and below:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "features.properties.TYPE": "8003" } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "features": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$features",
                            "as": "feature",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$feature.properties.TYPE", "8003" ] },
                                    "$$feature",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
     doc.features.forEach(function(feature) {  
        bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id, "features.properties.TYPE": "8003"  })
            .updateOne({ "$set": { "features.$.properties.TYPE": "8" });

        counter++;
        if (counter % 500 === 0 ) {
            bulk.execute();
            bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        }
    });
});

if (counter % 500 !== 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

**MongoDB 3.2 or newer**:

```
var ops = [];

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "features.properties.TYPE": "8003" } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "features": {
                "$filter": [                   
                   "input": "$features",
                   "as": "feature",
                   "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$feature.properties.TYPE", "8003" ] }
            }           
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.features.forEach(function(feature) {  
        ops.push({
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id, "features.properties.TYPE": "8003"  },
                "update": { "$set": { "features.$.properties.TYPE": "8" }
            }
        });
        counter++;      
    });

    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
});


if (counter % 500 !== 0) 
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

The counter variable above is there to manage your bulk updates effectively if your collection is large. It allows you to batch the update operations and sends the writes to the server in batches of 500 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 500 requests.

For bulk operations MongoDB imposes a default internal limit of 1000 operations per batch and so the choice of 500 documents is good in the sense that you have some control over the batch size rather than let MongoDB impose the default, i.e. for larger operations in the magnitude of > 1000 documents.

---

Adapting the above in Java would entail the following (**untested code**):

**Before 3.0**:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongo.getDB("yourDB");

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("yourCollection");

// create the pipeline operations, first with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
    new BasicDBObject("features.properties.TYPE", "8003")
);

// build the $project operations
BasicDBList eq = new BasicDBList();
eq.add("$$feature.properties.TYPE");
eq.add("8")
DBObject equalityClause = new BasicDBObject("$eq", eq);  

BasicDBList cond = new BasicDBList();
cond.add(equalityClause);
cond.add("$$feature");
cond.add(false);

DBObject conditionalOperator = new BasicDBObject("$cond", cond);

DBObject map = new BasicDBObject("input", "$features");
map.put("as", 1);
map.put("in", conditionalOperator);

BasicDBList setList = new BasicDBList();
setList.add(map);
setList.add(new BasicDBList().add(false));
DBObject setDifference = new BasicDBObject("$setDifference", setList);

DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("feature", setDifference);
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);

AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(match, project);

BulkWriteOperation bulk = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
for (DBObject result: output.results()) {
    System.out.println(result);
    for (Object feature: result.features) {
        bulk.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", result._id)
            .append("features.properties.TYPE", "8003")
        ).update(new BasicDBObject(
                "$set", new BasicDBObject(
                    "features.$.properties.TYPE", "8"
                )
            )
        ); 
    }
}       
BulkWriteResult result = bulk.execute();
System.out.println(result.isAcknowledged());
```

If you are using the **MongoDB Java Driver version 3.0** and newer, you can try (also **untested**):

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("yourCollection");    
List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();

Block<Document> bulkBlock = new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        for (Obj el: document.features) {
            writes.add(new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                new Document("_id", document._id)
                    .append("features.properties.TYPE", "8003"), 
                new Document("$set", new Document("features.$.properties.TYPE", "8"))
            ));     
        }
    }
};

collection.aggregate(asList(
    match(eq("features.properties.TYPE", "8003")),
    project(Document.parse("{
        'features': {
            '$filter': [                   
               'input': '$features',
               'as': 'feature',
               'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$feature.properties.TYPE', '8003' ] }
        }           
    }"))
).forEach(bulkBlock);

collection.bulkWrite(writes);
```